# SSIS Cannot Convert Unicode to non Unicode String Error

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

Our team has created a SSIS Package that imports data from an Oracle Source into a SQL Database, the package used Oracle Provicer for OLEDB to client to the Oracle SOR.

The major Data type difference between the Source and the Destiantion Databases is that while the Source has string columns has Unicode the Destination DB supports a non Unicode format.

We added Data conversion components and let the package run, while it works on the Development server (which has oracle 11g components) it does not seem to work on the Test server (Oracle 8 Installed)

Also we tried to add Cast Statements to the Source query, however the external and the output columns do not seem to pick up the Converted format.

Have tried, Dervied Columns, Data Conversions til now

Need Ideas badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the code to work by Setting the ValidateExternal Meta Data Property for the Source Task, also before starting development with SSIS and Oracle ensure you do have the Oracle Provider for .NET ODTwithODAC112030 package installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in one of the older versions of the oracle components -- to integrate with visual studio correctly (and still run under a 64bit environment post deploy) you need to use the ODAC112040 32bit -- note the older .30 version still had the bug;